# Trouble running sencha

Tags: ruby, extjs

I am facing lot of issues with sencha.

Ruby193 and sencha 3.1.2.342 is installed.

While I generate app i get below error

```
[ERR]
[ERR] BUILD FAILED
[ERR] java.lang.NullPointerException
[ERR]
[ERR] Total time: 0 seconds
[ERR] com.sencha.exceptions.BasicException
```

When I try to run sencha app build

I get below error

```
$ sencha app build
[ERR] null
     at com.sencha.tools.pkg.HttpRepository.fixUrl(HttpRepository.java:136)
     at com.sencha.tools.pkg.HttpRepository.<init>(HttpRepository.java:31)
     at com.sencha.tools.pkg.RemoteRepository$Type$1.create(RemoteRepository.jav
a:33)
     at com.sencha.tools.pkg.RemoteRepository.<init>(RemoteRepository.java:74)
     at com.sencha.tools.pkg.RemoteRepository.<init>(RemoteRepository.java:102)
     at com.sencha.tools.pkg.RemoteRepository.<init>(RemoteRepository.java:106)
     at com.sencha.tools.pkg.RepositoryRemoteManagerImpl$1.accept(RepositoryRemo
teManagerImpl.java:28)
     at java.io.File.listFiles(Unknown Source)
     at com.sencha.tools.pkg.RepositoryRemoteManagerImpl.<init>(RepositoryRemote
ManagerImpl.java:26)
     at com.sencha.tools.pkg.LocalRepository.<init>(LocalRepository.java:85)
     at com.sencha.command.environment.WorkspaceRepository.getLocalRepository(Wo
rkspaceRepository.java:113)
     at com.sencha.command.environment.WorkspaceRepository.getCatalog(WorkspaceR
epository.java:92)
     at com.sencha.command.environment.WorkspaceEnvironment.resolvePackageModels
(WorkspaceEnvironment.java:103)
     at com.sencha.command.environment.WorkspaceEnvironment.resolvePackageEnviro
nments(WorkspaceEnvironment.java:90)
     at com.sencha.command.environment.AppOrPackageEnvironment.getRequiredPackag
eEnvironments(AppOrPackageEnvironment.java:165)
     at com.sencha.command.environment.PackageEnvironment.getRequiredPackagesNoB
ases(PackageEnvironment.java:242)
     at com.sencha.command.environment.PackageEnvironment.<init>(PackageEnvironm
ent.java:77)
     at com.sencha.command.environment.WorkspaceEnvironment.loadPackageEnvironme
nt(WorkspaceEnvironment.java:163)
     at com.sencha.command.environment.WorkspaceEnvironment.getPackageEnvironmen
t(WorkspaceEnvironment.java:191)
     at com.sencha.command.environment.PackageEnvironment.getExtendPackageEnviro
nment(PackageEnvironment.java:99)
     at com.sencha.command.environment.PackageEnvironment.getBasePackageEnvironm
ents(PackageEnvironment.java:233)
     at com.sencha.command.environment.PackageEnvironment.getBasePackageNames(Pa
ckageEnvironment.java:262)
     at com.sencha.command.environment.PackageEnvironment.<init>(PackageEnvironm
ent.java:65)
     at com.sencha.command.environment.WorkspaceEnvironment.loadPackageEnvironme
nt(WorkspaceEnvironment.java:163)
     at com.sencha.command.environment.WorkspaceEnvironment.getPackageEnvironmen
t(WorkspaceEnvironment.java:191)
     at com.sencha.command.environment.PackageEnvironment.getExtendPackageEnviro
nment(PackageEnvironment.java:99)
     at com.sencha.command.environment.PackageEnvironment.getBasePackageEnvironm
ents(PackageEnvironment.java:233)
     at com.sencha.command.environment.PackageEnvironment.getBasePackageNames(Pa
ckageEnvironment.java:262)
     at com.sencha.command.environment.PackageEnvironment.<init>(PackageEnvironm
ent.java:65)
     at com.sencha.command.environment.WorkspaceEnvironment.loadPackageEnvironme
nt(WorkspaceEnvironment.java:163)
     at com.sencha.command.environment.WorkspaceEnvironment.getPackageEnvironmen
t(WorkspaceEnvironment.java:196)
     at com.sencha.command.environment.AppOrPackageEnvironment.getThemePackageEn
vironment(AppOrPackageEnvironment.java:245)
     at com.sencha.command.environment.AppOrPackageEnvironment.getThemePackageEn
vironments(AppOrPackageEnvironment.java:255)
     at com.sencha.command.environment.AppOrPackageEnvironment.getThemePackageNa
mes(AppOrPackageEnvironment.java:266)
     at com.sencha.command.environment.AppEnvironment.<init>(AppEnvironment.java
:54)
     at com.sencha.command.environment.BuildEnvironment.load(BuildEnvironment.ja
va:193)
     at com.sencha.command.Sencha.loadBuildEnvironment(Sencha.java:374)
     at com.sencha.command.Sencha.main(Sencha.java:127)
```

I have install and uninstall ruby and sencha 3 times...but no luck

Can any one help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed [JRE](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jre7-downloads-1880261.html)? You will also need to ensure you've set your OS [environment variables](https://superuser.com/questions/284342/what-are-path-and-other-environment-variables-and-how-can-i-set-or-use-them), namely that the PATH variable contains the location of Ruby and Sencha Cmd. Once this is done you will need to restart any open command line.